# HTTP Adapter for accessing SOAP WSDL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

i have a soap wsdl which i open have an field to enter an id that gives the link of an image to be displayed.I need to do this in ibm mobile first.i do no where to start it need some samples for soap wsdl help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate an adapter based on your web service by using the service discovery tool. Read more to learn how to generate it: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_using_service_discovery_wizard_to_explore_backend-services.html?lang=en